# How to add stack trace to core dump

Tags: gdb, stack, coredump

I want to automatically add a step to the core dump generation procedure (preferably for cores for certain process only but if not possible than for all processes will do as well).  I want to add a text file containing a chunk of the core in the same folder.

At the moment I am using the core_pattern to generate the core with a certain name and compress it so I basically want to run gdb on the core before compression print stack trace to file and than compress.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apport, which already [does much of what you want](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport#Report_format).